# Unable to upload "opencv_core242" after adding the files to application output directory

Tags: c#, opencv

I am new to Emgu CV in C# and when I tried to set it up on my 64-bit laptop, I added the required EmguCV .dll files as reference and the related opencv .dll files to the project or put the opencv .dll files to bin/debug folder in my project folder, I got the following error (I've changed my targeted platform to x64 and downloaded the x64 package):

```
System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233036
  Message=The type initializer for 'Emgu.CV.CvInvoke' threw an exception.
  Source=Emgu.CV
  TypeName=Emgu.CV.CvInvoke

  InnerException: System.DllNotFoundException
       HResult=-2146233052
       Message=Unable to load DLL 'opencv_core242': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)
       Source=Emgu.CV
       TypeName=""
       StackTrace:
            at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke.cvRedirectError(CvErrorCallback errorHandler, IntPtr userdata, IntPtr prevUserdata)
            at Emgu.CV.CvInvoke..cctor()
       InnerException:
```

I've been stuck to this for a few days and really appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, it seems that it won't find opencv_core242... I do not know why.
I would encourage you to try with 64bit 2.2 emgucv version dlls.